# Reset authentication flow from freemarker template

Tags: keycloak, freemarker

Is there a way to reset the current authentication flow from within a freemarker template? We have a complex login process with multiple chained authenticators. There is also a `cancel` button on most of the authenticators' challenge responses, which, at the moment, is an anchor tag with `href="${url.loginUrl}"` but clicking it doesn't have the desired effect: Keycloak remembers the state of the authentication session and thus instead of going back to the beginning, the current authenticator page simply reloads. Within the authenticator's code there is the possibility of `context.resetFlow()` to restore a pristine state of the authentication session. Is there a way to do this from freemarker as well?

**Edit:** my current solution is to use a `href=${url.loginUrl}&reset=true` in the template and a check on that query parameter in the authenticator which then triggers `resetFlow`. I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: Hello, did you ever solved this situation? I have currently exactly the same challenge. cheers

Comment: I did open a question related to a very similar topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76928439/in-a-keycloak-multi-step-authentication-process-using-custom-ftl-templates .Feel free to give it a look, and I did also mentioned this solution and referenced it.