# In a Keycloak "multi-step authentication" process (using custom .ftl templates), how can I go back to a previous step via href?

Tags: keycloak, freemarker

I'm using Keycloak server development dependency v.21

Due to some specific authentication logic requirement, I created a user authentication process in Keycloak divided into 3 steps:

1. An initial login & password step.
2. Displaying a login list of possible "available logins" for login selection.
3. After a login has been selected either authenticate or require a new password.

To implement the process described above, I created 3 different Authenticator classes, each of them using a corresponding custom .ftl template. I connected those 3 "authentication steps" using a custom "Browser flow" stacking the 3 authenticators after each other, configured through the Keycloak Authentication admin options.

So far so good. But there is one seemingly trivial element I haven't been able to accomplish, namely; the capability to either, "go back 1 step when I'm in the 2nd or 3rd step of the authentication process" or just restart the process by "going back to the 1st step". I guess there is an environment variable at the level of the template that I could use as a link to achieve that "step backwards", but I haven't been able to find it (if it even exists). I did try using href="${url.loginUrl}, but that always points toward the "current step" and never "points backwards" (I've also seen that the loginUrl is always the same no matter in which step I'm in, so that variable won't help...)

Could you please share some feedback regarding how to "go back via a link" towards a previous Authenticator ftl (perhaps by using an available ftl variable)? or any feedback at all (like pointing me to a relevant documentation or pertinent issue/post)?

PS: please do note I'm asking how to go back 1 step (or to the 1st step) within the authentication flow, and not how to go back to the Application (canceling the authentication flow), which I already do by using:

```
<#if client?? && client.baseUrl?has_content>
       <p><a id="backToApplication" href="${client.baseUrl}">${kcSanitize(msg("backToApplication"))?no_esc}</a></p>
</#if>
```

Thanks in advance.

**LATER EDIT:**
On this post: [Reset authentication flow from freemarker template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71419515/reset-authentication-flow-from-freemarker-template) , the author describes a very similar situation, and there it is partially answered the question of "jumping to the 1st authentication step" or just "reseting the authentication flow". So this part of the question is answered. The question that remains is if when having several chained authenticators, we could somehow natively move backwards without causing session problems or other authentication inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

Would using JavaScript to simulate back button work for your purpose?

```
<button onclick="history.back()">Go Back</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comment. This would correctly redirect at the browser level. However in the Backend Keycloak remembers the state of the authentication session and generates inconsistent page states when repeating the input of data.

Comment: Since I stated the question, this person here has a very similar situation (which I can use as a suboptimal solution): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71419515/reset-authentication-flow-from-freemarker-template